# Who was the Arrested Development Character in Avengers: Infinity War?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war, cameo, arrested-development

So while watching the credits to *Avengers: Infinity War* I noticed a special thanks to 20th century fox for An Arrested Development Character but I did not see a name for the character in the thank you.

I am wondering if anyone picked up on who it was or when it was as if any were in the movie it went straight over my head.

Comment: SF&F - https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/186361/which-arrested-development-character-was-in-infinity-war

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Alright seems a simple Google search would have done. It was Tobias, as clarified in [this article](https://www.cbr.com/avengers-infinity-war-arrested-development-easter-egg/):

> In Infinity War, Star-Lord, Gamora, Mantis and Drax return to Knowhere
>   in hopes of prying the Reality Stone from The Collector before Thanos
>   can get his hands on it. However, they arrive to find widespread
>   destruction. When they hear Thanos’ booming voice, they try to creep
>   up on the Mad Titan, and Star-Lord signals for his teammates to stop,
>   but no one does. As Gamora walks away, the top left corner holds the
>   mother of all Easter eggs: Tobias Fünke in his Blue Man Group makeup —
>   white cut-off shorts and all. He’s one of The Collector’s specimens in
>   the terrarium-like containment cells. Now, just to be clear, it’s not
>   actor David Cross, but it’s unmistakably Tobias.

Comment: Does that mean the MCU takes place in the same universe as Arrested Development?

Comment: It does kinda suggest that Arrested Development is in the MCU, especially seeing that the Stair Car appears in Civil War